# Any way to predefine an image for flattr-things?

Tags: flattr

Is there any possibility to manually define an image for flattered things?

Or are there plans by the devs to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the image using Open Graph metadata in the page that is submitted, like you do for eg. Facebook: http://ogp.me/

If you're using WordPress or such there's likely a plugin that you could use.

Comment: This solution seems to be most suitable for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just checked the API and there seems to be no way of defining the image upfront. Not with an auto-submit URL and not with the create-thing request.

Only thing I could find is once you created a thing, you can edit it using this URL:

```
https://flattr.com/thing/edit/<thing-id>
```

The form has a text field that is labeled **Change image by providing an url. (will take some time to update)**. Enter a URL to an image.

I tried it and it took about 30 secs to update.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. At the time I've asked this questions, this feature for manually entering an URL hasn't been implemented, yet!